# Recursively getting IDs of all Checkboxes checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion, traversal

I have an ASP.NET panel called pnlCategories. What I am trying to do is create a function that returns a List generic list of all Check Boxes that are checked inside this panel. There are other child controls (including other panels and tables) that this function will have to traverse through to find all the check boxes. Anyone have any ideas how to do this? This is C# by the way.

Comment: You could use javascript to build a string of id's then parse the string in C# to create the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, also untested. This could be adapted to only collect the controls IDs, but this is a little more reusable and is a great one to have in a common library.

```
    public static void FindControlsRecursive(Control root, Type type, ref List<Control> list)
    {
        if(root.Controls.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach(Control c in root.Controls)
            {
                if(c.GetType() == type)
                    list.Add(c);
                else if (c.HasControls())
                    FindControlsRecursive(c, type, ref list);
            }
        }
    }
```

And usage:

```
var checkboxes = new List<Control>();
FindControlRecursive(pnlCategories, typeof(CheckBox), ref checkboxes);

var ids = checkboxes.Select(c => c.UniqueID).ToList(); // or however you'd like to get them.
```

Comment: Tried this, but it did not find any controls at all for some reason. Trying to figure out why now.

Comment: At what point in the page lifecycle are you looking for the controls? Are you looking for them after a postback or the first time the page loads?

Comment: Ok, this works for me. The reason it didn't work before was from my own fault. This code works good, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say something like this (adapted) might work. I haven't tested this, but it should get you somewhere close.

```
public List<CheckBox> FindAllCheckBoxControls(WebControl webControl)
{
     if(webControl.Controls.Count == 0)
         return new List<CheckBox>();

     var checkBoxes = webControl.Controls
          .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox));
          .Select(x => x as CheckBox)
          .ToList();

     webControl.Controls.ToList().ForEach(control =>
        {
             checkBoxes.AddRange(FindAllCheckBoxControls(control));
        });

     return checkBoxes.Distinct();
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but gets a bunch of errors. The Linq code appears to be incorrect.